# Typescript mixin loose generic type

Tags: typescript, mixins

Consider the following, pretty basic example of typescript mixins:

```js
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

class Service<TDataType> {
  public foo(f: TDataType): Observable<TDataType> { return of(f); }
}

type GConstructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type ServiceConstructible<TDataType> = GConstructor<Service<TDataType>>;

function applyBarMixin<TDataType, TBase extends ServiceConstructible<TDataType>>(Base: TBase) {
  
  return class BarService extends Base{
    public bar(b: TDataType): Observable<TDataType> {
      return of(b);
    }
  };
}
```

When applying this mixin, the argument and return type of `b()` get lost (unknown):

```js
const FooBar = applyBarMixin(Service<number>);

const service = new FooBar();
let x = service.bar(1);
// x: unknown
```

Even the argument of `bar` is unknown! What am I missing here?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeQEYGcCmUBuBDVAG0wBo4IAzOAXzgqghDgHIoAPAK3WYG4AoPgGNCedOjgBlbDmCDMAHgAqAETww8igJ5hMAPkR84cMAFcisuhAgAKCgC44KtRu2YAlA7RZcBYktXqWjr6SFCYMCZQAHbkFLZuPDR81AIwrnAA4gDCEFHoMFAmgjDQSnAAvIjU%20pVRmADucNYAdK14UADm6A54UZoA2gC6bhX6ivxpOpLSspg5eQVFMMBECk6BrjWZ8-mFxaVSuLP%20zkF6uvx8FCZRxcC5cHhgYISaAELtALLAbMBR8oYjI4Ai4dCRAUZFB8sHBMGwYJgogATcSHGRyHaLO6rE4bYJ8XTWaGYBxQ0TuAxGQFhCLRODCUTiD5QNGzWHwxEouDEhAQuB80zmQRwVDtayoUkgs4eFAYaS%20NZSzaUoFGGmRGKUcUJPkpIzUfgpASCXL5OAAMSszIqj2er2Z31%20UWsrLk8iiJhAqGwuh1QlN8G86MwNrqjUtEGZ1h1xHgbBtQdmzVFUGsAEY-XwgA)

Answer (score 0):

The mixin itself is fine but the type error is within the service class. `Service<number>` is an instance of the service class and not the class itself.

Here is the working version:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

class Service<TDataType> {
  public foo(f: TDataType): Observable<TDataType> { return of(f); }
}

type GConstructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type ServiceConstructible<TDataType> = GConstructor<Service<TDataType>>;

function applyBarMixin<TDataType, TBase extends ServiceConstructible<TDataType>>(Base: TBase) {
  return class BarService extends Base {
    public bar(b: TDataType): Observable<TDataType> {
      return of(b);
    }
  };
}

const FooBar = applyBarMixin(Service);

const service = new FooBar<number>();
let x = service.bar(1);  // x: Observable<number>
```

Comment: Hmm I'll try that, but it makes sense. What I dont get, is why the compiler doesnt produce any error, since the generic on the mixin is not provided?

Comment: The TS compiler produces errors when your code violates type safety, but in this case, your code doesn't violate type safety; it just doesn't provide the type safety you expect.

Comment: but it _doesnt_ work.... https://tsplay.dev/wjaM1W what did I miss?